# hide soft key toolbar completely on kindle fire

Tags: android, kindle, kindle-fire

I can see the videos played in kindle fire has no soft key toolbar, How can I do this effect?

can I hide the soft key toolbar completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the Kindle SDK documentation - https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/cx-guidelines.html#Fullscreen - you'll see there are a couple of options. One hides everything, and the other leaves a small drag-handle to quickly get the toolbar back

Comment: I use exactly same code, but I can't hide the key toolbar. There is always a drag handler there.

Comment: are you on the original Fire (Gingerbread) or the new ICS devices? Can you post the code you're using? On the SDK site they also have some samples you can download (working for me on my Fire HD 7")

Comment: added your code to my test project as well as the manifest entry <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.permission.SET_FLAG_NOSOFTKEYS" /> and it works initially, but once the screen is tapped the drag handle doesn't disappear again. will have more of a look

Comment: drag handle doesn't automatically disappear. you have to re-apply the layout from code ... I misunderstood that bit

Comment: I try to re-apply the layout, but how can I do it? When I touch the screen, the drag handler shows, I setOnTouchListener, but the code(set full screen) inside the listener doesn't work. Does the system took over the touch event? How can I impliment it?